# Cause of race condition in producer/consumer stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, race-condition, producer-consumer

I've tried to create a producer-consumer stack, based on notification events, that would allow a single thread to push data, and another thread to pop data.

When the buffer is full/empty, one thread waits for another until it is able to continue.

I'm detecting a race condition (the program breaks where I have marked `***ERROR HERE***`) but I don't understand why it can happen.

How can `size` go higher than `capacity` in this program?

```
#include <process.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

template<typename T, typename Ax = std::allocator<T> >
class rwstack
{
    // It is assumed that only ONE thread will push data
    //   and only ONE thread will pop data.

public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Ax allocator_type;
    typedef rwstack<value_type, allocator_type> this_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type, allocator_type> container_type;

private:
    allocator_type allocator;
    value_type *items;
    size_t volatile count;
    size_t const capacity;
    HANDLE hEventNotEmpty, hEventNotFull;
    rwstack(const this_type &other) { __debugbreak(); /*Don't allow*/ }

public:
    rwstack(const size_t capacity = 4096)
        : allocator(allocator_type()),
        items(allocator.allocate(capacity, NULL)),
        count(0), capacity(capacity),
        hEventNotEmpty(CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL)),
        hEventNotFull(CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL)) { }

    virtual ~rwstack()  // Not actually used in the example
    {
        CloseHandle(hEventNotEmpty);
        CloseHandle(hEventNotFull);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        { allocator.destroy(&items[InterlockedDecrementSizeT(&count) - i]); }
        allocator.deallocate(items, capacity);
    }

    value_type &push(const value_type &value)
    {
        const ULONG waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hEventNotFull, INFINITE);
        if (waitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0) { __debugbreak(); }
        const size_t newSize = InterlockedIncrementSizeT(&count);
        try
        {
            if (newSize > capacity) { __debugbreak(); }  // ****ERROR HERE****
            if (newSize >= capacity) { ResetEvent(hEventNotFull); }
            allocator.construct(&items[newSize - 1], value);
            SetEvent(hEventNotEmpty);
            return items[newSize - 1];
        }
        catch (...) { InterlockedDecrementSizeT(&count); throw; }
    }

    void pop(value_type *pValue = NULL)
    {
        const ULONG waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hEventNotEmpty, INFINITE);
        if (waitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0) { __debugbreak(); }
        const size_t newSize = InterlockedDecrementSizeT(&count);
        try
        {
            if (newSize > capacity) { __debugbreak(); }  // ****ERROR HERE****
            if (newSize <= 0) { ResetEvent(hEventNotEmpty); }
            if (pValue != NULL) { *pValue = items[newSize]; }
            allocator.destroy(&items[newSize]);
            SetEvent(hEventNotFull);
        }
        catch (...) { InterlockedIncrementSizeT(&count); throw; }
    }
};

static size_t InterlockedIncrementSizeT(size_t volatile *p)
{
#if _M_X64
    return InterlockedIncrement64(reinterpret_cast<long long volatile *>(p));
#elif _M_IX86
    return InterlockedIncrement(reinterpret_cast<long volatile *>(p));
#endif
}

static size_t InterlockedDecrementSizeT(size_t volatile *p)
{
#if _M_X64
    return InterlockedDecrement64(reinterpret_cast<long long volatile *>(p));
#elif _M_IX86
    return InterlockedDecrement(reinterpret_cast<long volatile *>(p));
#endif
}
```

Test code:

```
typedef rwstack<int> TTestStack;

void __cdecl testPush(void *context)
{
    TTestStack::value_type v;
    for (;;)
        static_cast<TTestStack *>(context)->pop(&v);
}

void __cdecl testPop(void *context)
{
    for (TTestStack::value_type v = 0; ; v++)
        static_cast<TTestStack *>(context)->push(v);
}

int main()
{
    TTestStack rw;
    HANDLE hThreads[2] = {
        reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthread(&testPush, 0, &rw)),
        reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthread(&testPop,  0, &rw)),
    };
    const ULONG nThreads = sizeof(hThreads) / sizeof(*hThreads)
    WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreads, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it in the simplified case of setting capacity=1, and if so, do you still have the problem?

Comment: Just want to be know, since you are working on windows you don't have access to ppl ?

Comment: @HostileFork: Didn't get a chance to test it, but I'll try it the next time I across a problem like this.

Comment: Just wanted to know, if we can't use ppl instead of using threads. Nothing related to answering the question.

Comment: @jagansai: I'm confused, what's "ppl"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You aren't locking the correct operation

The key here is that while you are disabling the `hEventNotFull` event in Thread A, you are also enabling it in Thread B.

### Threads Run Concurrently

So here's what is happening:

1. The queue is full at 4096 items.
2. Thread B obtains the lock and decrements the count to 4095.  You need to hold this lock until you decide whether or not to enable `hEventNotFull`, but you immediately release it.  The OS pauses Thread B for a moment.
3. Thread A obtains the lock and increments count to 4096.  You need to hold this lock until you decide whether or not to reset `hEventNotFull`, but you immediately release it.
4. The OS decides that Thread B is more important than Thread A.
5. So you wind up calling `resetEvent` in Thread A followed by `SetEvent` in Thread B.  Net result is that you'll return to execution in Thread A and count == 4096.

### Flow of Execution:

```
Thread B: Get count and decrement it to 4095.  # Queue not full
Thread A: Get count and increment it to 4096.  # Queue full
Thread A: ResetEvent on `hEventNotFull`        # A thinks it will block since queue is full
Thread B: SetEvent on `hEventNotFull`          # B is using stale info and unblocks A
```

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks so much for the awesome explanation! :) I was hoping to avoid a critical section in the average case but I guess it's inevitable now (though I still need to check to make sure).